# Check if Java ArrayList of HashMap<String,String> contains a key

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have this type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>` . I want to check if a key exist in that array list . I can do this through a for loop but is there any alternative way to do this ?

Comment: The loop is the easiest. Is there a particular reason you're looking for an alternative?

Comment: Where do you get the list from? What is in those HashMaps(i.e. anything special or basically random String to String mappings)?

Answer (score 0):

While building those individual HashMaps, if you could build a **super** hashmap, then there is no need for for loop. But don't know if it is possible for you. Just look-up in that super-hashmap.

Comment: That could be bug prone, especially if you remove some elements.  Duplication of data is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Along the line of @Bhushan's answer, create a new class that encapsulates the ArrayList of maps, and a Map of the key values.  E.g.

```
public class EncapsulatedLookup {
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data;
    private Map<String, Integer> keyToArrayListPosition lookup; 
}
```

Add methods to ensure whenever you add/remove from `data`, you also update the `lookup`

Answer (score -3):

The most easiest way that comes into my mind and maight work is to extend the HashMap class and implement .equals() method. Anyway, this method also internally uses interation.